# Interpolated and literal Perl strings in Nano are incorrectly highlighted

Tags: regular-expression, nano

I am trying to improve Nano's syntax highlighting for Perl, but I have run into an interesting dilemma. Perl uses single quotes for literal strings, and double quotes for interpolated strings. The problem with this is that if I have a single quote in an interpolated string or vice versa, the next time I use that quote character, Nano will highlight from the middle of the prior string to the next use of the quote character, like so:

```
           v--  highlighted another color  --v
print "What's up Johnnie boy!\n"; print "What's up with you?\n";
```

**Is there a way to set up the perl.nanorc file so that I don't match a pair of single quotes whose first quote character is in between a double quote pair?**